# Condition rendering for login fields in xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I come from a react background but recently have had to do more xml as part of my job.

Currently understand you can display different layouts if a user does something. However if a user is logging in. Say username and password and when a field is empty i want the drawable to flip to red. Creating a new layout seems odd? Can I not use ternary similar to JSX for example.

```
android:background=" isValid ? @drawable/good : @drawable/error"
```

where isValid is a boolean and in its respective file I check if it is empty or not and display an alert if it is. But cant seem to change the layout dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simple way is to put 2 drawable icons 1 is normal and second is red, set one image view beside username edit field. Now in your java class when you are checking for field , if it empty set red icon else set normal icon into respective imageview username or password.

Comment: @pratikvekariya ok thank you. will give it a shot.

Comment: all sorted now thank you. Pointed me in the right direction :)